# Show connected systems over a network on a webpage

Tags: windows, networking

While I am connected to a network (Windows) and I go to NETWORK, I see a list of systems curently connected over same network, that have shared their files nd folders.

Is there any way to show that list on a webpage and also the list of files and folders shared inside those systems. (like PHP scandir())

I know that PHP natively cannot do this, but may be a combination of C (or Java) and PHP, such that a C program pushes that list towards PHP.
How is this posible?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by creating an executable binary file that scans your dirs and outputs data in a form PHP can parse (e.g. a JSON string), and calling that binary from your PHP using the [`exec`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php) function. Example:

C:

```c
int main() {
    /*
    * Any code that outputs a JSON-encoded string
    * to stdout.
    */
    printf('"anObject" : { "data" : "example" , "foo" : "bar" }');
    return 0;
}
```

This can be any executable file that outputs anything to stdout, like a python script or even a shell script.

PHP:

```php
<?php
    $json = exec('myexec');
    $object = json_decode($json);
    /*
    * You can now do whatever you want in php with that 
    * object you've just recreated from the JSON
    */
?>
```